# How do I unset a variable at the command line?

Tags: shell, yaourt

I have tried the following command to set Proxy on `yaourt`:

```
export ALL_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

The question is how to unset the proxy on `yaourt`?
In general, how can I unset the value of a variable in the current shell?

Comment: Try `unset ALL_PROXY`

Comment: @coffeMug might as well make that into an answer, you could also consider stealing some info from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12263914/1081936

Comment: in addition to the accepted answer, if there's a command you often run that uses an environment variable that you'd rather not set or change for the rest of your shell session, you can run it like: `$ ALL_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:8080 yaourt` that will set the envvar only for the command run. You can put as many `FOO=bar BAZ=bat` variables as you want prior to the command to run.

Comment: LAUGHING OUT LOAD ..

Answer (score 295, accepted):

To remove an environment variable, run

```
unset ALL_PROXY
```

Note that an environment variable only takes effect in a program and the program it launches. If you set an environment variable in one shell window, it doesn't affect other shell windows.

If you've added `export ALL_PROXY=…` to an initialization file, remove it from there.

You can run `export` with no arguments to see what environment variables are set in the current shell.

Remember that to make a shell variable available to the programs started by that shell, you need to export it, either by running `export VAR` after the assignment `VAR=VALUE` or by combining the two (`export VAR=VALUE`).

Comment: I think it's not essential that the `export VAR` occur after the assignment. Observe: `sh -c 'export F; F=2; sh -c "echo F2=\$F"; echo F1=$F'` prints "F2=2\nF1=2".

Comment: `unset` is also required to clear associative bash arrays (ie: bash "hash tables", or "dicts"), as this tutorial explains under the section titled "Clearing": https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/.

Answer (score 41):

To unset a bound variable in bash use `unset VARIABLE` (`unset ALL_PROXY` in your case).
This command actually deletes the variable. You can also set the value of a variable to empty by

```
VARIABLE=
```

or

```
VARIABLE=""
```

The difference is that the two latter commands don't delete the variable.
You can see the difference by using the `-u` flag with `set` to force it to treat the unset variables as an error while substituting:

```
/home/user1> var=""
/home/user1> echo $var

/home/user1> set -u
/home/user1> echo $var

/home/user1> unset var
/home/user1> echo $var
-bash: var: unbound variable
```

In the above example, bash complains about `var` is unbound (after unsetting its value) which is the expected error (note that this does not happen in second echo command, meaning that `var` has a value which is `empty` or `null`).

Comment: what if I have a variable in my shell script file and I source that file, then how am I going to unset that?

Comment: @Abhinav use `unset` in the script. Same applies.